# Custom command and 'extra data' that ends up as undefined

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I'm trying to overwrite the Cypress `within` method such that there's an extra argument for the callback.

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to go
`cy.customCommandThatSetsAValue().within((subject, extra) => {})`

The issue seems to be a matter of timing... whenever I try to pass a non-hardcoded value, it ends up being passed as undefined. I've tried a number of permutations and it seems like somehow even when I set the variable from within a `.then()` callback, it's undefined when it gets to the custom command.

Here's my override:

```
function within<Subject>(
    originalWithinFn: Cypress.CommandOriginalFnWithSubject<'within', Subject>,
    prevSubject: Subject, 
    optionsOrFn: Partial<Cypress.Loggable> | WithinCallback,
    fnOrUndefined?: WithinCallback,
){
    let fn: WithinCallback;
    let options: Partial<Cypress.Loggable> | undefined;
    if (optionsOrFn instanceof Function && fnOrUndefined === undefined) {
        fn = optionsOrFn;
    } else if (fnOrUndefined instanceof Function) {
        options = optionsOrFn;
        fn = fnOrUndefined;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid arguments provided to cy.within');
    }
    return getMostRecentNavigationShorthand().then(mostRecentShorthand => originalWithinFn(prevSubject, options!, (subject) => fn(subject, mostRecentShorthand)));
}

Cypress.Commands.overwrite('within', within);
```

A simplified version of `customCommandThatSetsAValue()` is

```
return cy.get('foo').then(() => {mostRecentShorthand = anObject});
```

and

```
function getMostRecentNavigationShorthand() {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(mostRecentShorthand));
}
```

I've tried changing the return in `within` to

```
return cy.then(() => 
    getMostRecentNavigationShorthand()
        .then(mostRecentShorthand => 
            originalWithinFn(prevSubject, options!, (subject) => fn(subject, mostRecentShorthand)
)));
```

as well as trying to wrap a `cy.then` around the promise (or use that instead of a promise). No matter what i do, it still ends up undefined at actual execution time.

Any idea how/why I keep getting undefined or how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I put all that code into a test, it passes. Don't know what `anObject` is, so I just used `{abc: 123}`.

```js
let mostRecentShorthand = null

function getMostRecentNavigationShorthand() {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(mostRecentShorthand));
}

function within(originalWithinFn, prevSubject, optionsOrFn, fnOrUndefined) {

  // parameter resolving

  return getMostRecentNavigationShorthand()
    .then(mostRecentShorthand => {
      return originalWithinFn(prevSubject, options, (subject) => 
        fn(subject, mostRecentShorthand)
      )
    })
}
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('within', within)

Cypress.Commands.add('customCommandThatSetsAValue', () => {
  return cy.get('h1').then(() => {mostRecentShorthand = {abc: 123}})
})

it('gives an extra parameter to within', () => {
  cy.visit('https://example.com');
  cy.customCommandThatSetsAValue().within((subject, extra) => {
    expect(extra).to.deep.eq({abc: 123})
  })
})
```

You would not need the `Cypress.Promise` block since you set the value synchronously, immediately resolve, and never reject. But it does not cause the extra parameter to be `undefined`. That would only happen if the value of `anObject` were `undefined`.

Comment: Very strange... I replaced setting that value by hand with `cy.wrap(theValue).as('___mostRecentShorthand').get('foo')` and suddenly it isn't undefined anymore. But now the command override is complaining about mixing sync and async, even though the only changes over there were replacing `getMostRecentNavigationShorthand` with another `cy.get` chain

Comment: And that error appears to have been caused by returning `originalWithinFn` as opposed to just calling it